# useState is not woking

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can anyone tell me why this country not set in setCountry state via axios.i am fetching data from api via axios.i have below attched my response data from api.

```
function Country() {
    const [Country, setCountry] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        //IF [] , runs only once
        const fetchUrl="https://api.first.org/data/v1/countries"
       async function fetchData(){
           
           const request=await axios.get(fetchUrl);
           setCountry(request.data);
           return request;
 
       }
       fetchData();
    
    },[]);

    return (
        <div>
            <button >load country</button>
            <select>
            

            </select>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Country
```

response data from api in console.log

```
{status: "OK", status-code: 200, version: "1.0", total: 251, limit: 100, …}
access: "public"
data: {DZ: {…}, AO: {…}, BJ: {…}, BW: {…}, BF: {…}, …}
limit: 100
offset: 0
status: "OK"
status-code: 200
total: 251
version: "1.0"
```

Comment: It looks like you're expecting `country` to be an array but the `data` returned from the API is an object.

Comment: so how can i get it

Comment: I see no issue here. What or how are you validating state isn't updating or working?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're looking for, but maybe `setCountry(Object.values(request.data));`?

Comment: You should not use Capitalized Country as state variable. It's convention that component names are capitalized. Now you have two variables named Country. The component and the state variable. How do you know the state country is not set? Maybe you are logging the wrong Country? I would suggest changing the state country variable from Country to country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are accessing through API response is an object. Maybe what you can do is something like this -

`setCountry(Object.values(request.data));`

The `request.data` will be an object with below structure -

```
request.data = {
       "DZ":{"country":"Algeria","region":"Africa"},
       "AO":{"country":"Angola","region":"Africa"},
       "BJ":{country":"Benin","region":"Africa"}
       ....
}
```

Now passing this into `Object.values` will return an array which you can directly set into the component state.

```
Object.values(request.data) = [
   {country: "Algeria", region: "Africa"},
   {country: "Angola", region: "Africa"},
   {country: "Benin", region: "Africa"},
   ....
]
```

Comment: I don't think we've enough context yet to definitively say the state is being updated to object vs array and this being the issue of "state update not working". ***Clearly*** there's a mismatch from initial state and the response shape, but even given this discrepancy the state update would still occur.